# How many valid matrices are there that share the same row / column totals for n=4?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, combinations

I have been thinking of a problem that I cannot solve by myself. I would really appretiate any help. Let's assume I am studying a bus line in one (and only one) direction, with $n$ stops numbered 1 to 4 (for example):

```
    1      2      3      4
    o ---> o ---> o ---> o
```

I could represent the trips on the bus line as a matrix:

$$
\begin{matrix}
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 0 & t_{12} & t_{13} & t_{14} \\
2 & 0 & 0 & t_{23} & t_{24} \\
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & t_{34} \\
4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

Since the bus line is one direction only, no one can go in the oposite direction, and it doesn't make sense to board and alight on the same stop, so the diagonal and the bottom triangle should all be 0. There can be any number of trips: $t_{12}$ is any natural number ($\mathbb{N}$). It doesn't make sense to have a negative, fractional or real number of trips.

I can calculate the total number of boardings and alightings at each stop, as they are just the rows and columns totals (respectively):

$$ Boardings_i = \sum_{j=1}^4 t_{ij}$$
$$ Alightings_i = \sum_{i=1}^4 t_{ij}$$

Everyone getting on the bus should get down at some point, so total boardings must equal total alightings:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^4 B_i = \sum_{i=1}^4 A_i $$

Now, let's assume I know this totals for rows and columns (the number of people boarding and alighting on each stop), $(B_i, A_i) \in \mathbb{N}$ , and I want to find a matrix ($t_{ij}$) that produces these totals. **How many matrices are there that add up to these row and column totals?**

I have tried to develop an intuition for this. I know the solution is trivial for $n = 2$, and there is one and only one solution for $n = 3$, as I can express the problem as a system of linear equations:

\begin{align}
B_1 & = t_{12} + t_{13} \\
B_2 & = t_{23} \\
A_2 & = t_{12} \\
A_3 & = t_{13} + t_{23} \\
B_1 + B_2 & = A_2 + A_3 \\
\end{align}

I am stuck there. I know for $n = 4$ the number of possible solutions depend on the total number of trips. For higher values of $(B_i, A_i)$, I should expect a higher number of solutions possible. Except the matrix structure counts: there is only one valid solution for $B_i = [x, x, x, 0], A_i=[0, x, x, x]$, regardless of the value of x. Specifically, high values in the right-top matrix cells $(t_{13}, t_{14}, t_{24})$ seem produce higher number of possible solutions (degrees of freedom?), $t_{12}$ and $t_{34}$ seem to reduce the number of posible solutions, while other matrix cells next to the diagonal (e.g. $t_{23}$) seem to provide no information / have no effect because their values are determined from other matrix cells. For example:

- $B_i = [8, 4, 2, 0], A_i=[0, 0, 6, 8]$ allows for 5 different matrices resulting in the given row and column totals
- $B_i = [8, 5, 1, 0], A_i=[0, 0, 6, 8]$ allows for 6 different matrices resulting in the given row and column totals
- $B_i = [8, 6, 0, 0], A_i=[0, 0, 6, 8]$ allows for 7 different matrices resulting in the given row and column totals

Any guidance on how to tackle this is much appretiated. Any tips on how to generalize the solution to $ n > 4 $ are also much appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the $n=4$ case you can straightforwardly solve it as follows. First set up the equations explicitly:

$$t_{12}+t_{13}+t_{14} = b_1\\ t_{23}+t_{24} = b_2\\ t_{34} = b_3\\ t_{14}+t_{24}+t_{34} = a_4\\ t_{13}+t_{23} = a_3\\ t_{12} = a_2$$

Isolate as many of the $t$ variables as possible. Here I have expressed them all in terms of $t_{13}$ and the constants:

$$t_{34} = b_3\\
t_{12} = a_2\\
t_{14} = b_1-a_2-t_{13}\\
t_{23} = a_3-t_{13}\\
t_{24} = b_2-a_3+t_{13}\\
b_1+b_2+b_3 = a_2+a_3+a_4$$

Note that the last equation has no variables in it any more, showing the constraint that the rows and the columns have the same total sum.

All the variables need to be non-negative, and this gives the following constraints for $t_{13}$:

$$t_{13}\le b_1-a_2\\
t_{13}\le a_3\\
a_3-b_2\le t_{13}\\
0\le t_{13}$$

Every value of $t_{13}$ that satisfies these constraints leads to a valid solution of the matrix. These constraints can be combined into a single range:

$$\max(0,a_3-b_2) \le t_{13} \le \min(a_3,b_1-a_2)$$

The number of solutions is therefore $\min(a_3,b_1-a_2)-\max(0,a_3-b_2)+1$.

I think that for larger $n$ this method will be is less useful, as there will be more than one degree of freedom, making it more complicated to count the number of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is not gettign much attention, so I have tried to brute-force my way through it. I will leave my work so far here in case it is useful to someone else.

You can follow the same approach I followed for n=3 and define system of linear equations that can be solved in python using sympy:

```
from sympy import Matrix, solve_linear_system, solve

#TODO: Generalize to n>4. Use symbolic ecuations.
def matrix_solution_to_trip_ends_1L_1D_n4(TOs, TDs):
    '''Given two vectors for trip origins (row totals) and trip
    destinations (column totals), returns a parametric matrix consistent
    with the input trip ends.'''
    
    try:
        assert len(TOs) == len(TDs) == 4
    except AssertionError:
        raise ValueError('Trip end vector must have equal length.')
    
    coefs = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
             [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
             [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
             [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
             [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]]
    const = TOs[:-1] + TDs[1:]
    
    A = Matrix(coefs)
    b = Matrix(const)
    system = (A, b)
    
    solution = linsolve(system)
    
    t12, t13, t14, t23, t24, t34 = (solution.args[0])
    T = Matrix([[0, t12, t13, t14], [0, 0, t23, t24], [0, 0, 0, t34], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
    
    return T
```

For example, you can do: `T = matrix_solution_to_trip_ends_1L_1D_n4([8,4,2,0],[0,0,6,8])`. T contains a parametrized matrix consistent with the input vectors of boardings and alightings:

```
Matrix([[0, 0, tau0 + 2, 6 - tau0], [0, 0, 4 - tau0, tau0], [0, 0, 0, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

You can also define functions to find the range of tau0 values for which all matrix cells are positive:

```
def rng_valid_matrices(T):
    '''Given a matrix T of solutions (matrices with specific total trip
    ends) based on a single variable, returns the range of that variable
    that produces valid matrices.'''

    maximums = []
    minimums = []
    for x in T:
        try:
            sol = solve(x)[0]
            if x.could_extract_minus_sign():
                maximums.append(sol)
            else:
                minimums.append(sol)
        except:
            continue
    rng = (max(minimums), min(maximums))
    return rng

def n_rng(rng):
    '''Given a range from n to m, both inclusive, as a tuple (n, m),
    returns the number of natural numbers included.'''
    # n_mats = len(range(*rng)) + 1
    n_mats = rng[1] - rng[0] + 1
    return n_mats
```

`n_rng(rng_valid_matrices(T))` will output the number of valid matrices: 6.

I haven't been able to answer the question mathmatically or generally, but at least now I can solve the problem for any specific example. Any help is still appretiated.

```
>>> n_rng(rng_valid_matrices(matrix_solution_to_trip_ends_1L_1D_n4([8,4,2,0],[0,0,6,8])))
    5
>>> n_rng(rng_valid_matrices(matrix_solution_to_trip_ends_1L_1D_n4([8,5,1,0],[0,0,6,8])))
    6
>>> n_rng(rng_valid_matrices(matrix_solution_to_trip_ends_1L_1D_n4([8,6,0,0],[0,0,6,8])))
    7
```